# Easy way of converting a string to lowercase in python

Tags: python

I have a text as follows.

```
mytext = "This is AVGs_ABB and NMN_ABB and most importantly GFD_ABB This is so important that you have to CLEAN  the lab everyday"
```

I want to convert it to lowercase, except the words that has `_ABB` in it.

So, my output should look as follows.

```
    mytext = "this is AVGs_ABB and NMN_ABB and most importantly GFD_ABB this is so important that you have to clean  the lab everyday"
```

My current code is as follows.

```
splits = mytext.split()
newtext = []
for item in splits:
   if not '_ABB' in item:
        item = item.lower()
        newtext.append(item)
   else:
        newtext.append(item)
```

However, I want to know if there is any easy way of doing this, possibly in one line?

Comment: Sure, one could invent one-liners for this, but what exactly is wrong with your version? It is significantly more readable.

Comment: @Kendas I wouldn't say so; nobody would expect to see so much code for that task. Creates too many variables too

Comment: `mytext.replace("_ABB","_abb")`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a one liner splitting the string into words, check the words with `str.endswith()` and then join the words back together:

```
' '.join(w if w.endswith('_ABB') else w.lower() for w in mytext.split())
# 'this is AVGs_ABB and NMN_ABB and most importantly GFD_ABB this is so important that you have to clean the lab everyday'
```

Of course use the `in` operator rather than `str.endswith()` if `'_ABB'` can actually occur anywhere in the word and not just at the end.

Comment: May use ```... if '_ABB' in w```, since the question asks for "words that has _ABB in it". It doesn't have to be at the end

Comment: Still I'd write it as `if  '_ABB' in w`, just so that it applies to what OP asked for *words that has `_ABB` in it*

Answer (score 3):

Extended *regex* approach:

```
import  re

mytext = "This is AVGs_ABB and NMN_ABB and most importantly GFD_ABB This is so important that you have to CLEAN  the lab everyday"
result = re.sub(r'\b((?!_ABB)\S)+\b', lambda m: m.group().lower(), mytext)

print(result)
```

The output:

```
this is AVGs_ABB and NMN_ABB and most importantly GFD_ABB this is so important that you have to clean  the lab everyday
```

---

Details:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?!_ABB)` - lookahead negative assertion, ensures that the given pattern will not match
- `\S` - non-whitespace character
- `\b((?!_ABB)\S)+\b` - the whole pattern matches a word NOT containing substring `_ABB`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possible(not elegant) one-liner:

```
mytext = "This is AVGs_ABB and NMN_ABB and most importantly GFD_ABB This is so important that you have to CLEAN  the lab everyday"

print(' '.join(map(lambda x : x if '_ABB' in x else x.lower(), mytext.split())))
```

Which Outputs:

```
this is AVGs_ABB and NMN_ABB and most importantly GFD_ABB this is so important that you have to clean the lab everyday
```

**Note:** This assumes that your text will only seperate the words by spaces, so `split()` suffices here. If your text includes punctuation such as`",!."`, you will need to use regex instead to split up the words.